# GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails STATUS Definitions

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-subscriptions

I'm checking the payment profile statuses with GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails, however I cannot find any documentation on the definition of the statuses returned.

The STATUS could be:

- Active
- Pending
- Cancelled
- Suspended
- Expired

Active, Pending and Expired are straight forward enough but was about "cancelled" and "suspended". Does a "suspended" account have anything to do with reversals or refund attempts? What about cancelled?

[API documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/mx/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails)

Answer (score 1):

Suspended means the subscription is temporarily on hold on the user's end either due to the user placing it on hold or paypal due to payment not going through.

Cancelled means the user cancelled the subscription within paypal

Comment: Is there anyway to tell if the subscription was cancelled/suspended due to a reversal or refund claim?

Comment: Not through the subscription api directly. I believe that if they do a charge back, the single payment api will ping you and the subscription will be cancelled.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, I don't want to depend on any IPN service and want to check directly. Thanks.